# How to add filp efect to epub pages using Turn.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, epub, turnjs

I have an .epub file that does not have any effect or animation while user turns between the pages

I use [Turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/) library for it be it does not work .I can not open it with eBook readers softwares.

Here is my Epub folder Directory

**Before** add Turn.js library

[image: befor]

**After** add Turn.js library
 [image: after]

And here is my **chap_0001.xhtml** Html code

```html
  <head>
    <title>How to Win Every Argument</title>
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width = 1050, user-scalable = no" /><!-- Added-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extras/jquery.min.1.7.js"></script><!-- Added -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="extras/modernizr.2.5.3.min.js"></script><!-- Added-->
  </head>
  <body dir="auto">
  <h1 dir="ltr" class="center">How to Win Every Argument</h1><p dir="ltr" class="center bold">Madsen Piri</p>
  
 <div class="offset">
  <div class="flipbook-viewport"><!-- Added-->
 <div class="container"><!-- Added-->
  <div class="flipbook"><!-- Added-->

  <div style="width: 100.0%;">
  <img src="images/img_0001.png" alt="Picture #1"/>
  </div>
  <span xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" id="1" title="1" epub:type="pagebreak"/>
  <div style="width: 37.238758708043065%;">
  <img src="images/img_0002.png" alt="Picture #2"/>
  </div>
  <span xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" id="2" title="2" epub:type="pagebreak"/>
  <div style="width: 45.59848005066498%;">
  <img src="images/img_0003.png" alt="Picture #3"/>
  </div>
  
  <!-- rest of pages -->
       </div> 
   </div> 
   </div> 
  </div>
```

And here is my **chap_0001.xhtml** Js code

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
//Added after using Turn.js library
    function loadApp() {
      // Create the flipbook
      $('.flipbook').turn({
        // Width
        width: 922,
        // Height
        height: 600,
        // Elevation
        elevation: 50,
        // Enable gradients
        gradients: true,
        // Auto center this flipbook
        autoCenter: true

      });
    }

    // Load the HTML4 version if there's not CSS transform

    yepnope({
      test: Modernizr.csstransforms,
      yep: ['lib/turn.js'],
      nope: ['lib/turn.html4.min.js'],
      both: ['style/basic.css'],
      complete: loadApp
    });
```

**I only copy library folders and change chap_0001.xhtml file . That's it.**

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Did you add Jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what particular issues you had with your script. One main issue is the extra spans you included in your html:

```
<span xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" id="1" title="1" epub:type="pagebreak"/>
<span xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" id="2" title="2" epub:type="pagebreak"/>
```

They were considered "pages" and therefor turn.js turned the page to blank span that does not have the same size as other elements.

Anyway, this is a working example with your html: [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/2jwc1b8d/)

*I could not include working code here because turn.js is served over http. I had to copy the entire code and paste into js part which is more than stackoverflow text limit*